# How to print errors while streaming with tweepy in python?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, ioerror

I am a Python newbie and am trying to print error messages when using Tweepy to stream tweets. I used an endless loop in my streaming code because it generates InComplete Read errors otherwise. My aim is to print all the error messages I get while continuing to stream tweets, so that I am aware of errors other than the InComplete Read errors.

My streamListerner is:

```
# Code from http://badhessian.org/2012/10/collecting-real-time-twitter-data-    with-the-streaming-api/ with minor modifications
import json, time, sys
from tweepy import StreamListener

# create an instance of a tweepy StreamListener to handle the incoming data. 
class SListener(StreamListener):

    def __init__(self, fprefix = 'streamer'):
        # self.api = api or API()
        self.counter = 0
        self.fprefix = fprefix
        self.output  = open('../Dissertation/stream_3_data/' + fprefix + '.' + time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') + '.json', 'w')
        self.delout  = open('delete.txt', 'a')

    def on_data(self, data):

        if  'in_reply_to_status' in data:
            self.on_status(data)
        elif 'delete' in data:
            delete = json.loads(data)['delete']['status']
            if self.on_delete(delete['id'], delete['user_id']) is False:
                return False
        elif 'limit' in data:
            if self.on_limit(json.loads(data)['limit']['track']) is False:
                return False
        elif 'warning' in data:
            warning = json.loads(data)['warnings']
            print warning['message']
            return False

    def on_status(self, status):
        self.output.write(status)

        self.counter += 1

        if self.counter >= 5000: # New file is started every 5,000 tweets, tagged with prefix and a timestamp.
            self.output.close()
            self.output = open('../Dissertation/stream_3_data/' + self.fprefix + '.' 
                           + time.strftime('%Y%m%d-%H%M%S') + '.json', 'w')
            self.counter = 0

        return

    def on_delete(self, status_id, user_id):
        self.delout.write( str(status_id) + "\n")
        return

    def on_limit(self, track):
        sys.stderr.write(track + "\n")
        return

    def on_error(self, status_code):
        sys.stderr.write('Error: ' + str(status_code) + "\n")
        return True # Don't kill the stream

    def on_timeout(self):
        sys.stderr.write("Timeout, sleeping for 60 seconds...\n")
        time.sleep(60)
        return True # Don't kill the stream
```

The part that seems to generate problems is when I try to use the streamlistener:

```
twitter_api = tweepy_oauth()
Q = "twitter.com"

locations = [101.615161,3.08115,101.753663,3.167507,
         115.421372,39.43277,117.501099,41.05999,
         120.858322,30.69094,121.9733,31.86889]

# Create a streaming API and set a timeout value of 60 seconds.
streaming_api = tweepy.streaming.Stream(twitter_api, SListener(), timeout=60)

# Used infinite loop from https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython/issues/288 cause 
# I kept getting InComplete Read Error. Probably due to high volumes of tweets being sent to me at once

#Endless loop
while True:  
    try: 
        streaming_api.filter(follow=None, track=None, locations=locations, stall_warnings=True)
    except:
        e = sys.exc_info()[0]  #Get exception info
        print 'ERROR:',e  #Print exception info
        continue
```

My code does run and works, but I encounter the following error occasionally, which stops my entire stream:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IOError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-fb45fa5d8307> in <module>()
      34         streaming_api.filter(follow=None, track=None, locations=locations, stall_warnings=True)
      35     except:
      36         e = sys.exc_info()[0]  #Get exception info
 ---> 37         print 'ERROR:',e  #Print exception info
      38         continue

 IOError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

The timing when the error appears is inconsistent - it ranges from 1h into the stream to an entire day into the stream.

I concluded that the issue is with the print statement because I replaced line 37 with

```
print 'Error'
```

and the same error message appears. I am not sure how to proceed when even the basic print statement does not work - any help would be great.

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: I've tried to run the code on Enthought Canopy version 1.4.1 (64 bit) and on ipython notebook with the same results. Both should be Python 2.7.